# Pass multipart/form-data between two perl projects using Mojo

Tags: perl, multipartform-data, mojolicious

So I need to pass multipart form data between two projects. First project code (I get form data and do some actions there):

```
    my $formdata = $self->req->params->to_hash;

    //some actions with $formdata here
    $data_request->{some_content} = {content => $formdata->{contentstr}};
    $data_request->{filedata} = {file => $formdata->{filename}};
    my $headers = {
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
    };
    my $url = Mojo::URL->new($conf->{host});
    $url->path($conf->{my_url});

    my $tx = $ua->post($url => $headers => form => $data_request);
```

But for some reason I can't get the file in the second project using

```
$self->req->upload('filename')
```

If I upload the file in the first project it works fine. Content parameters are available in the second project, but not the file. Why can't I just pass binary data?

Comment: You are missing some sigils on $data_request and $formdata. What is $formdata->{filename}? Is the first form a file upload?

Comment: True, I edited the question now. Yes, I guess $formdata->{filename} contains binary file data which was sent by the client.

Comment: That's unlikely; form parameters in $self->req->params would not contain file uploads in a multipart form, you'd have to get the file upload from `$c->param('file')` or `$c->req->upload('file')` or `$c->req->uploads`. This would be a Mojo::Upload object, which has an `->asset` method returning the asset you can pass as `file`.